# jQuery Mobile - Issue with caching in a multipage template

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I've got a problem with a jquery mobile app i'm working on.

Basically in one particular part of the app I have search results which list 6 items per page, and x number of JQM pages, all within the same actual page. I've done it as a multipage template so you can slide and swipe left and right through the results and it looks nice and slick.

The search results have a requirement to order by date and alphabetically, so you can toggle between the two. The logic for this is all done serverside, I just link to the same physical url but with a query string to switch to date order. Like so....

```
<div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true" class="orderOptions">       

  <a href="/Default.aspx?orderBy=atoz" id="MainContent_rptBrochures_BrochureList_2_btnAtoZ_2" data-role="button" data-theme="a" class="sortOptions ui-btn-active ">A-Z</a>       

  <a href="/Default.aspx?orderBy=date" id="MainContent_rptBrochures_BrochureList_2_btnDate_2" data-role="button" data-theme="a" class="sortOptions">Date</a> 

</div>
```

The trouble is, if I click the Date button, the transition loads in the first JQM page from the new reordered result set, but not the other pages. It keeps all the other pages from the AtoZ result set as well. I need all the Date result set and none of the AtoZ set (these need to be removed).

I hoped adding a query string would sort of make it appear like its a new page request and avoid all the caching stuff but it appears not!

What I dont want to do is make clicking the link do a full refresh (which does work) as we lose the nice transitions. Was wondering if anyone could think of a way round this? Or come across something similar?

Cheers, Will